# Figuring out how much torque dc motor will need to run at a certain speed. (E-skateboard project)

Tags: dc-motor, speed, torque

Suppose I want to purchase a DC motor online, how can i determine how much torque my motor will need to run at a certain speed? I.e. 15mph

This is for my electric skateboard project and the load on top of the board will be 140 lbs.

Really having a hard time figuring this out and was hoping someone can share their knowledge.

Comment: Your specs lack hill incline capability,  time to full speed and $ budget and capacity to improvise mechanically and build electronics -1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a mechanical physics or mechanical engineering rather than electrical engineering calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Get a friend to tow you behind a car while you ride a conventional skateboard. Use some type of spring scale to measure how hard the tow rope is pulling you. That force, multiplied by the radius of the skateboard wheel, is the required wheel torque. If your skateboard uses a drive-belt, then the motor torque will be different than the wheel torque. The rope should be long enough that you are not in the slipstream of the car. I suggest you take measurements at several speeds and also while going up and down a few hills. Make sure you record both speed and force. The speed component will allow you to calculate power as well as torque.

Comment: (oh, and safety cautions: get **two** friends, one driving the car and one on the board. Not too close friends.)

Comment: this is more of a comment than a solution

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, it is a direct answer to the question. The question is "how can i determine how much torque my motor will need to run at a certain speed?" The alternative is to make assumptions about friction coefficients and aerodynamic drag. The OP would be wise to consider hill climbing ability and acceleration capability as well. If the motor has just enough power to cruise at 15mph, it may not be very fun to ride, and will have no ability to go up hill.

Comment: Yes but a naive question at that.  Sometimes when I see this, it is pointless to answer a question that cannot possibly lead to  practical solution.  I prefer to add intelligence to the answer when the question shows no clue about how to do the overall concept. So a literal answer is  equally naive to me. No disrespect.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the same is true for skate boards but for bicycles you can find online calculators like these; [Cycling calculator](http://www.bikecalculator.com/examples.html).  I would think at 15mph the rolling friction and wind resistance would be similar.  For me this calculator says 160lbs of me and 20lbs of bicycle take 110 Watts.  In this case, I'm the motor and putting out about 100rpm at the crank.  Your motor will turn a lot faster.  It turns out on the mechanical side the power a motor puts out is equal to the motor speed in rad/sec times the torque in Nm.  Now if you search for small motors like this you might come up with these;[Maxon 150W Motors](http://www.maxonmotorusa.com/maxon/view/category/motor?etcc_med=Product&etcc_cmp=%2Fmaxon%2Fview%2Fcontent%2Fa-max-motors%3Fetcc_med%3DProduct%26etcc_cmp%3D%252fmaxon%252fview%252fcontent%252fa-max-motors%253fnoMobile%26etcc_cu%3Donsite%26etcc_var%3D%255bus%255d%2523en%2523_d_%26etcc_plc%3Dproduct_index%26noMobile&etcc_cu=onsite&etcc_var=%5Bus%5D%23en%23_d_&etcc_plc=product_index&target=filter&filterCategory=amax)  You need to know your battery voltage.  If you pick one of the 48V motors and run it on the fast side, to get good efficiency, say 7000rpm.  This is about 700rad/s.  So this motor would be at 110W/700rad/s = 0.15Nm.  If you picked a different motor that was most efficient at 3500 rpm your torque would double to put out the 110 Watts needed.  See?

Comment: A skateboard wheel does not spin at 7000 RPM. Depends on size, of course, but more like 2000 RPM, as a ballpark number.

Comment: @mkeith The motor can run at what ever speed you want it to. You need some kind of transmission gears belts or such.  5

Comment: yes. That is my point, also.

Comment: @mkeith It seemed like you thought the motor had to spin at the at the wheel speed.  What would you guess the motors are spinning at in the picture in Tony Stewart's answer.  I'm guessing about five times the wheel speed.

Comment: I don't consider that to be a skateboard. Probably not what the OP had in mind, either. The motors probably spin at 3000 to 4000 rpm. Just because those are typical numbers for motors.

Answer (score 0):

Torque is about acceleration, not about speed. The higher the torque, the faster you speed up. To calculate the actual acceleration, you need the impulse required, which is governed by the load to accelerate.

**In contrary**, the top speed is limited by the driving power your whole arrangement needs and has. The motor torque goes into that equation **but not the impulse** and thus, not the load on top of the board (because it isn't accelerated any more).

Instead, losses get important. Most influencing losses come from

- the wheels on the ground (but then: more loss there leads to higher possible acceleration – no slippage)
- the loss of the gear (but then: a worm gear may be much smaller)
- and head wind (don't laugh: wear a cape and see the difference, plus: wind losses go up with \$v^2\$)

You have to find out these losses first to calculate the top speed possible. To make a rough guess, for the wind shape of a single person riding a vehicle at 15mph, you need about 1kW mechanical power. That's what mopeds have.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. However I thought that torque was inversely proportional to rotational speed. I am just looking for a way to get a rough estimate like you said without taking into consideration your bullet points. How did you come up with 1kW? Which is 1,000 watts I believe. How did you get this answer? Thanks.

Comment: In general, no. That's a property of a series DC motor, because the field strengh depends on the motor speed. Do you want to use a series DC motor? I find that hardly unlikely, you sure want to use a PMDC motor instead. That one has permanent magnets creating the field so it's contant. Same with torque, it's nearly constant over all speeds.

Comment: -- hardly unlikely --> unlikely. Sorry.

Comment: The 1kW come from the passionate driving of a moped in my youth. It had 1kW mechanical power and a top speed of roughly 15mph on a flat road with no outer wind. If you wonder about that high number, consider the wind loss depends on speed^3. That means when your top speed is only 5mph, you only need 1/27 (1/3*1/3*1/3) the power for fighting against head wind.

Comment: Ah, have to correct myself v^3 is energy, not power. For power, it's v^2.

Comment: A cyclist at 15mph (leisurely) is producing closer to 150W than 1000W.

Comment: Well, I then wonder why my moped had 1kW and still reached only 15mph. It was built in 1970 so no fancy electronics limiting the speed. And I may be untrained but I hardly reach 15mph on my bike by *leisurely*. It's hard work.

Comment: 150W may be enough for cruise at 15 mph on flat ground (not saying it is, but it might be). But the skateboard, to be fun, should have more power so it can climb hills and also so it can accelerate to max speed at a reasonable rate.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think you can build one cheaper than buying one engineered with over 10 man years of R&D and low cost materials in China?  I say this, not to discourage your thinking, but to encourage you to learn how write a better list of requirements. Cost, performance, functions accessories. Not just weight and speed.  There is a lot more to Engineering than Grade 12 Physics.

[image]
This picture is worth about $850 with charger and remote control.
Rated at 3300W with 35 kph but not sure for how long as this would get very hot.

Answer (score -2):

This may help you get started. Don't expect a detailed design service.

- design spec:

  - 4 wheel skate board 65mm wheels , 65kg load plus motor+bat
  - desired speed 35 km/h on smooth level road. let's use 36kph=10m/s

\$ E_k=\frac{1}{2}mv^2=(65+15kg)100/2=4kW-s=4kJ\$

- Thus for 1/3 Hp~=750/3=250W
- However HP = T*RPM which peaks around 80-85% ideally so using an average of 1/3 for the area under a triangular rising HP you have an avg Hp of 1/9th Hp or 750W/hp/9= 83W mechanical power so time to full speed is 4000Ws/83W=48 seconds so you see, leg power is faster.
- Next motor rating is Torque in kV/RPM with D=65mm wheels with a circumference of 204mm = 0.2m and a velocity, v = 10m/s
- for RPM= v/(Pi*D)*60 =10/(3.14*65)*60*1000mm/m = 3000 RPM

> So you are looking for a 1/3Hp pancake brush DC motor with 3000 RPM no load. then choose Wh batt size and voltage from different assumptions for standard voltages in this type and size then pick lowest kV/RPM avail to get highest string of series voltage.

The max loaded speed is where F=T/r or friction=torque/radius of wheel. (edited typo.

> Think of it like picking your favorite gear in a 10 speed bike. But you can only pick one gear, so it a compromise of acceleration and speed.

- Don't expect much acceleration as  a=F/m where 140lbs(65kg) is a lot more than friction at 15mph (35kph). Expect to use leg power to start and stop fast and don't expect much torque going up hill unless you choose a 2 speed motor with dual winding options

A good fit for HP ends up having loaded speed at 80% of no loss speed so max speed is 19mph or 44 kph.

- Then make sure your Zbat or battery ESR is much lower than DCR of motor for battery load regulation like <<10%DCR pref <2%. Use the highest voltage motor and series/parallel array voltage that is practical.

background info

---

- Direct current (DC) motor design

  **motor parameters (brush dc motor)**
- \$ v  \$= input voltage to the motor (volts)
- \$ rm\$ = motor resistance (ohms) or DCR in
- \$lm \$= motor inductance (henrys)
- \$ kb\$ = back emf constant (volt·s/rad)
- \$  kt \$= torque constant (N·m/a)
- \$ jm \$= rotor inertia (kg m²)
- \$ bm\$ = mechanical damping (linear model of friction: bm * dth)

  **load parameters**
- \$  jl \$=  load inertia (1000 times the rotor)
- \$ bl\$ =  load damping (friction)
- \$ k \$=  spring constant for motor shaft to load
- \$   b \$=  spring damping for motor shaft to load

  **Variables**
- \$  i  \$   =  motor electric current (amperes)
- \$  dth_m\$ =  rotor angular velocity sometimes called omega (radians/sec)
- \$  th_m \$ =  rotor angle, theta (radians)
- \$   dth_l \$=  wheel angular velocity (rad/s)
- \$ th_l \$ =  wheel angle (radians)

  **Equations**

  - \$ lm*i - v = -rm*i -    kb *th_m \$
  - \$jm*dth_m =  kt*i - (bm+b)*th_m - k*th_m +     b *th_l + k*th_l\$
  - \$jl*dth_l =             b *th_m + k*th_m - (b+bl)*th_l - k*th_l\$
  - \$dth_m = th_m\$
  - \$dth_l = th_l \$

Comment: Are there series DC motors that small to include them into a skateboard? I had the impression they all use PMDC motors.

Comment: Thank you, I don't quite understand your formulas though. I know that T = F x R but how does friction = speed with applied load?

Comment: the speed is limited by friction just below no load speed rating of motor in kV/RPM. , if friction or gravity exceeds torque/radius , then you stall. Do you know Kinetic energy at 35kph for 80kg incl motor&bat? convert to HP with 20% loss then compute kV/RPM for 65mm wheels (only use metric units)